# How to import a DateTime similar to UTC time

Tags: r, datetime

I get the following Datetime output from a datalogger: "2021-09-07T11:31:53.268-07:00", and it vaguely appears like UTC.

But, I am having trouble importing it. I've tried a number of ways, and the closest seems to be "cols(`Time Stamp` = col_datetime(format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s")", but this doesn't work.

The presence of the `T`, and what I assume is a time zone designation on the end throws me off.

Comment: Does `lubridate::ymd_hms("2021-09-07T11:31:53.268-07:00")` get you what you expected? For me that outputs "2021-09-07 18:31:53 UTC", which reflects the 7 hour timezone offset from UTC.

Comment: @JonSpring, thats perfect! Worked like a charm, thank you for the assistance!